# how to translate a div on button click with increase in opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to translate a div on button click  with increase in opacity? initially div opacity is zero.I want div need to translate from `300px` to `0px` with increase in opacity from `0 to 1` on button click .

my translate is not working . opacity is working fine.

here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-snowflake-hgekv?file=/index.html:0-850

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: left opacity 2s ease-in-out 0s;
      }
      .new {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function abc() {
        document.querySelector(".div").classList.add("new");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div"></div>

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 300px;">
      <button onclick="abc()">Play</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add transition property separately with a `comma(,)` like this:

`transition: left 2s ease, opacity 2s ease-in-out 0s;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: left 2s ease, opacity 2s ease-in-out 0s;
      }
      .new {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function abc() {
        document.querySelector(".div").classList.add("new");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div"></div>

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 300px;">
      <button onclick="abc()">Play</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following css into your new class

```
.new {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }
```